# How to avoid creating order with the same custom meta key values on the checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Customer "A" created an order, and entered the value "100" in the custom field. How can I prevent customer "C" from creating an order if he specifies the value "100" in a custom field? Since an order with the value "100" already exists?

Please help me, here is my attempt to implement it... What am I missing to make the code work? I can't figure out how to do it. Sample code :

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_woocommerce_billing_field');
    function custom_woocommerce_billing_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_code'] = array(
        'label'       => __('Code shipping', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => __('s9855', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'    => true, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'class'       => array('billing_code'),   // add class name
        'priority'    => 5, // Priority sorting option
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Save
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'shipping_code_update_order_meta' );

function shipping_code_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_code'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_code', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_code'] ) );
    }
}


// Checking  the field 

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_proces');

function my_custom_checkout_field_proces() {
    // Checking whether the field is filled in or not.
    if ( ! $_POST['billing_code'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter the delivery code.' ), 'error' );
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', ' custom__billing_code_validation', 50, 2  );


function custom__billing_code_validation( $data, $errors ) {
    if ( isset( $data['billing_code'] ) ) :

    global $wpdb;

    $billing_code = sanitize_text_field( $data['billing_code'] );

    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_billing_code'
        AND pm.meta_value != $billing_code 
        AND pm2.meta_key LIKE '_billing_code'
        AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '$billing_code'
    " );

    if ( $count > 0 )
        $errors->add( 'validation', __('The "Code" already exist, please contact us.') );

    endif;
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Why are you using the `$orders` object as a `meta value`?

Comment: I added a custom field on the checkout page. I need to check this field so that the meta value is unique for each order. If the user enters an already existing meta value, the order is not processed, and an error is displayed. "The code has already been used in another order! Please enter a different value!"

Comment: Can you update the full code to the question, please? with custom field

Comment: I have updated all the code . Here is the code I inserted into my functions PHP.

Comment: Where is the action hook for callback function `custom_woocommerce_billing_field` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simplify the query to something like this. I am assuming you are using the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` hook to add an error on checkout.

```
function custom__billing_code_validation( $data, $errors ) {

    $billing_code = isset( $data['billing_code'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $data['billing_code'] ) : '';

    if ( ! empty( $billing_code ) ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND p.post_status IN ( 'wc-pending', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold', 'wc-completed' )
            AND pm.meta_key = '_billing_code'
            AND pm.meta_value = %s
        ", $billing_code ) );

        if ( $count > 0 ) {
            $errors->add( 'validation', __('The "Code" already exists, please contact us.') );
        }
    }

}
```

I Tested this code and working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which hook you are using?

Comment: Thank you dear friend! It's not the first time you've helped me out! God grant you good health!